# Warning on Eclipse project with no warnings inside... why?

Tags: eclipse, warnings, project

I have warning on project but i don't have any warnings inside it.
How to get rid of it?

[screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img837/1539/0m8i.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img837/1539/0m8i.png)

Comment: When you put the mouse over there, what does eclipse say ?

Comment: Look in the `Problems` view, there may be something there

Comment: When i put the mouse over it Eclipse do not say anything.
In the Problems i have nothing related to that project